# how to get multidimentional associate array keys in one array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array dataand every array has its own values in array too  As below :

```
$array['loc']=array('india','usa','germany');   
$array['loc1']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc2']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc3']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc4']=array('india','usa','germany');
```

I want key list in one array like below:

```
$list['keys']=array('loc','loc1','loc2','loc3');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_keys

```
$array = [];
$array['loc']=array('india','usa','germany');   
$array['loc1']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc2']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc3']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc4']=array('india','usa','germany');   

$list['keys'] = $keys = array_keys($array);
print_r($list['keys']);
```

[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ecea14d24d52a873dd9def8a3b5a62eafbc85dd7).

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => loc
    [1] => loc1
    [2] => loc2
    [3] => loc3
    [4] => loc4
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) method like so:

```
array_keys($array)
```

This will give you an array of all your locations. As you want an array `$list` array of these keys, you can build your array using:

```
$list["keys"] = array_keys($array)
```

See example below:

```
$array['loc']=array('india','usa','germany');   
$array['loc1']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc2']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc3']=array('india','usa','germany');      
$array['loc4']=array('india','usa','germany');   

$list["keys"] = array_keys($array);

print_r($list["keys"]);
```

**Output**:

```
Array ( [0] => loc [1] => loc1 [2] => loc2 [3] => loc3 [4] => loc4 )
```